# How to create certificate for internal ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have created Internal Load Balancer for communicating my applications. And Currently I want to open HTTPS port with certificate. How to create that ?

```
1. SelfSigned certificate is not allowed.
2. Cert Only Signed by Amazon Authority,
3. DNS/EMAIL Validation Failed (Request a public certificate),
```

Anyone AWS expertise please advise me, how we can create that ?